# How to get notification iPhone device orientation when MPMoviePlayer is playing?

Tags: iphone, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have added notification observers for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification in my appDelegate. But it is not getting called when movieplayer is visisble. But works fine with other views.

Comment: UPDATE : 

use [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginDeviceOrientationNotificationEvents]

Comment: You should make your comment into an answer.